# Grunt css-min paths

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I have the following setup in my Grunt file for css

```
cssmin: {
        options: {
            rebase: true,
        },
        concat: {
            files: {
                'dist/app.css': [
                    'tmp/*.css',
                    'app/theme/css/vendors/fontello.css',
                    'app/theme/js/vendors/revolution/css/settings.css',
                    'app/theme/css/styles.css',
                    'app/theme/css/media-queries.css',
                    'app/app.css'
                ]
            }
        },
        min: {
            files: [{
                src: 'dist/app.css',
                dest: 'dist/app.css'
            }]
        }
    },
```

It works great except one tiny issue. The paths are rebased to start with 'app/theme/...' or 'app/images/...' however all my files are moved into a dist folder for uploading to production. Instead I want it to generate paths such as '/theme/...' or '/images/...'

Comment: are you using grunt-usemin? Usemin replaces references for you.

Comment: Yep, this one to be exact: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin

Comment: No, that's cssmin, not usemin: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

Comment: Consider using Less. Without changing the files (aside from the file extension), you can create proper CSS files with all of the imports resolved. Also, it gives you extra features to CSS (like variables and the such) should you want.

Comment: That wont help my 3rd party libraries though :(, im sure this must be a simple option to resolve

Comment: You could use grunt-usemin as i've already mentioned. It would also be beneficial (regardless of using usemin or not), to use a CSS preprocessor like Sass, or Less.

Comment: Seems like its just as difficult to do what i want

Comment: Ben, you can easily achieve exactly what you want by using sass, less or grunt-usemin. Why don't you give one of them a try?